# Link de WhatsApp não funciona em iOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp

Estou desenvolvendo uma landing page onde haverá um ícone com link para o WhatsApp.
Segui  [esse tutorial](https://alemdamidiasocial.com.br/criar-link-whatsapp/).

```
http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=55XXXXXXXXXXX
```

No Android funciona perfeitamente, conforme imagem: [image]
Porém, no iOS não funciona, quando o usuário clica no link ele é levado para a página do WhatsApp na App Store.

Existe alguma particularidade no iOS? O link precisa ser feito de forma diferente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estranho, eu utilizo o mesmo link de compartilhamento num site e funciona normalmente no iPhone.

Eu até pedi, agora há pouco, para uma amiga testar no iPhone dela para tirar dúvida e está tudo normal.

Por via das dúvidas, tenta utilizar a nova URL de compartilhamento do Whatsapp:

```
https://wa.me/<NÚMERO NO FORMATO INTERNACIONAL>
```

Exemplo: `https://wa.me/5511999999999`

Se quiser enviar uma mensagem pronta, a URL será

```
https://wa.me/<NÚMERO NO FORMATO INTERNACIONAL>?text=<MENSAGEM CODIFICADA PARA URL>
```

Exemplo: `https://wa.me/5511999999999?text=OlaMundo`

Outra sugestão da documentação do Whatsapp é utilizar Share Extension e `UIActivityViewController`.

Tenta também testar em outro aparelho iOS. Existe uma mínima possibilidade do problema ser o dispositivo.

**Referências**

- [Usando a Conversa em um Clique](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?lang=pt_br)
- [I'm an iPhone developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp into my app?](https://faq.whatsapp.com/pt/iphone/23559013)

Comment: Eu testei com o seguinte código https://wa.me/555499999999?text=teste e não funcionou no iPhone.

Comment: Estranho, deveria funcionar. Não funciona em nenhum iPhone ou é em um dispositivo específico? Aqui esses links funcionam normalmente. Dá uma olhada nos links que eu deixei na resposta, são da documentação oficial do Whatsapp.

Answer (score 1):

Por algum motivo algo mudou na página do WhatsApp web que é o link que ele abre primeiro (isso pode ter a ver com o Safari) quando abrir a página da web antes de clicar em "enviar mensagem" araste a página para baixo come se fosse atualizar, você verá que vai aparecer a opção de "abrir no app whatapp" é só clicar ali e ele abrirá o WhatsApp na tela de envio de mensagem... Espero ter ajudado.